How to go back to the root when a TabView is the root?
I would like to jump back to the root after arriving at ChatView2. However this doesn't work when I have a TabView in root.  What could I be missing in my code please?
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var stackingPermitted: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                FirstTabView(stackingPermitted: self.$stackingPermitted)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
            
            Text("Other Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Other", systemImage: "star")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstTabView: View {
    @Binding var stackingPermitted: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: NextView(stackingPermitted: self.$stackingPermitted)
            ) {
                Text("Go to Next View")
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("First Tab")
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    @Binding var stackingPermitted: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ChatView2(stackingPermitted: self.$stackingPermitted)
            ) {
                Text("Go to Chat View")
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
            .navigationBarTitle("Next View")
        }
    }
}

struct ChatView2: View {
    @Binding var stackingPermitted: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Chat View")
            Button(action: {
                self.stackingPermitted = false // Reset to root view
            }) {
                Text("Go Home")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Chat")
    }
}


Note, NavigationView is deprecated, use NavigationStack. In your case use NavigationStack(path: ...), then set the path to root or empty to go back to the root view. SeeNavigation See also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78183289/returning-to-home-view-with-navigationstack/78183812#78183812

Whatever tutorial you are following that uses NavigationView you should discard.

NavigationView is deprecated in iOS 16. Instead I finally got NavigationStack working.  In a way it is better because you can define the whole navigation in one place.
import SwiftUI

// Define an enum for navigation destinations
enum Destination: Hashable {
    case firstTabView
    case nextView
    case chatView
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var navigationPath = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink("Go to First Tab View", value: Destination.firstTabView)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Root")
                .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .firstTabView:
                        FirstTabView(navigationPath: $navigationPath)
                    case .nextView:
                        NextView(navigationPath: $navigationPath)
                    case .chatView:
                        ChatView2(navigationPath: $navigationPath)
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
            
            Text("Other Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Other", systemImage: "star")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstTabView: View {
    @Binding var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Go to Next View", value: Destination.nextView)
                .navigationTitle("First Tab")
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View {
    @Binding var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Go to Chat View", value: Destination.chatView)
                .navigationTitle("Next View")
        }
    }
}

struct ChatView2: View {
    @Binding var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Chat View")
            Button(action: {
                self.navigationPath = NavigationPath() // Clear the navigation stack
            }) {
                Text("Go Home")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Chat")
    }
}

